# Retrieve item's price history on Steam market

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

Regarding items from Steam market I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the price history of an item over a period of time.

I know that Steam provides a special api for developers who want to integrate market specific data into their own sites but I haven't been able to find anything about retrieving price history for an item in the form of a json.

Have any of you already done this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've done some more research and found the way you can retrieve the price history for an item.

As an example for those who are curious, the price history for this random item "Specialized Killstreak Brass Beast" can be retrieved in this way:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Specialized%20Killstreak%20Brass%20Beast

Comment: for this `API` response i can't call from `PHP`, i have to login to browser then i can get response otherwise it give me `[]` only as response.

Answer (score 3):

If calling from code

```
url ="http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/"
```

and the query string payload is:

```
{
    "country" = "US",      # two letter ISO country code
    "currency"= 1,       # 1 is USD, 3 is EUR, not sure what others are  
    "appid"   = 753,     # this is the application id.  753 is for steam cards  
    "market_hash_name"  ="322330-Shadows and Hexes" # this is the name of the item in the steam market.  
}
```

country code is the [ISO Country Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

you can find the app id for a game from the URL of its store page.  Example: The game "CS:GO" app id is 730.  [Store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/)

You can find the market hash name from the URL of its market page.  Example: [This CS:GO item](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Glove%20Case%20Key) hash name is "Glove Case Key".

Price history for the Glove Case Key is [here](http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Glove%20Case%20Key).

Comment: for this API response i can't call from PHP, i have to login to browser then i can get response otherwise it give me [] only as response.