# Get Steam Market price history using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, steam-web-api

I am trying to fetch Steam Market price history for an item, using Python. I am aware this is a common problem, but having tried every solution I found, I still get an empty list when I try, for example, this (using the `requests` module):

```
requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PT&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Falchion%20Case', cookies={'steamLogin': steamid}).content
```

I get `steamid` by writing `document.cookie` on the javascript console while logged in on Steam and copying the value for `steamid`.

(I got the price history link from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086658/retrieve-items-price-history-on-steam-market). It seems to be the best option to get price history, and works perfectly when I manually access it while logged on Steam.)

It might be useful to note that I have Steam Guard on my account.

Maybe I am missing something obvious. How should I emulate being logged in to make this request?

Comment: If you completely log out of your steam account and attempt to do the login through the web access by using selenium to input username and password ? Perhaps?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri then there would be a problem with Steam Guard, right? I'd would like not to enter a different code every time I launch my program